# Store and Read Objects in an Android Hide Folder

Tags: android, java-io, android-file

I need to store and read objects in Android, these Object must be available until they are manually deleted through the app.

Since I cannot use the assets folder for this,

How could I store objects in an hide folder to access them in future?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep them in your app specific directory in SD card. If you want the content inside your directory should not be scanned by mediascanner (so that they will not appear in Gallery etc), you need to keep a ".nomedia" file in that directory.

for example, create a directory called "mytestapp" in sdcard, and keep a ".nomedia" file there, along with the files you want to store

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me some sample code? I haven't never used the storage file in Android

Comment: What exactly you need the sample code for ? reading/writing files? http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: a sample to see how to create a directory with a .nomedia file in an accessible path (independently of the device model) where store and read a generic object (for example a list of Car object)